# Python websocket automatically closes with basic auth

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, basic-authentication

I am attempting to setup a websocket using the websocket-client library using python 3.7. The documentation from the API provider states that basic auth is required.

Below is the code I am using to try subscribing to their test channel. The test channel should send responses back nonstop until we close the socket.

```
email = b'myemail@domain.com'
pw = b'mypassword'
_str = (base64.b64encode(email + b':' + pw)).decode('ascii')
headerValue = 'Authorization: Basic {0}'.format(_str)

def on_message(ws, msg):
    global msg_received
    print("Message received:     ", msg)
    msg_received += 1
    if msg_received > 10:
        ws.send(json.dumps({"unsubscribe": "/test"}))
        ws.close()


def on_error(ws, error):
    print("ERROR:     ", error)


def on_close(ws):
    print("Closing websocket...")


def on_open(ws):
    print("Opening...")
    ws.send(json.dumps({'subscribe': '/test'}))
    time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    websocket.enableTrace(True)
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://api-ws.myurl.com/",
                                header=[headerValue],
                                on_message=on_message,
                                on_error=on_error,
                                on_close=on_close))
    ws.on_open = on_open
    ws.run_forever()
```

When I run this, I am able to see my request headers, and their response headers which show that the connection was upgraded to a websocket and I am assigned a Sec-Websocket-Accept. Then, the websocket immediately closes without any responses coming through.

I have tried first sending a post request to the login api and generating a sessionID and csrftoken, and then passing those as cookies in the websocketapp object. It didn't work. I have tried passing the headers as an actual dict but that doesn't work either. I've tried way too many variations of the b64 encoding and none of them work.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: what "API provider" ?What don't you add url to "API provider" so we could see documentation ?

Comment: @furas Because the API is not available publicly and neither is the documentation - you need to be a customer of the provider to have access to their portal and documentation

Comment: if we have no access to documentation then we can't say how it works and how to help you. Every API may expect different elements, requests, etc. Sorry.

Comment: @furas thank you! I scoured their documentation more and it turns out they want their csrf token in a very specific way. It is working now